# No "\n" after line.rsplit in python

Tags: python, string

I want to create a new text file and cut the string in each line.

```py
for line in rescut:
    rescutfinal.write("pretext_" + line.rsplit('delimiter', 1)[-1] + "1\t0\t10\tLinear\t0\t0")
```

But my code doesn't work as expected. My Outpout contains a new line after the "line.rsplit"-string

```
pretext_linesplitstring
string after linesplitstring pretext_linesplitstring
string after linesplitstring pretext_linesplitstring
string after linesplitstring pretext_linesplitstring"
```

How do I get rid of the "\n" after the linesplitstring?

Comment: `for line in rescut:` will deliver lines with newlines at the end.  Taking the last part after `rsplit()` will leave the newline.  Do `line.rstrip().rsplit('delimiter', 1)[-1]`.  If there is trailing whitespace you need to preserve do `line.rstrip('\n').rsplit('delimiter', 1)[-1]`.

Comment: ...which is to say -- before posting a question, ensure that the code sample *can actually be run* by someone else to see the problem themselves (so they can then change it in accordance with a proposed answer and run it again to test), while being the shortest possible thing that meets that goal; as described in the [mcve] page in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use str.rstrip() or str.strip():

```
line.rstrip().rsplit('delimiter', 1)[-1]
```